# Getting nearby places based on the User's current location

Tags: google-places-api

Can any one please suggest me to use any standard API to get the nearby hotel list based on the User GPS location.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) you could perform a [Places Search Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests) where `location` is the users lat,lng and `types=lodging` to search for hotels:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=lodging&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You will need to follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication) to obtain an API Key to use the service.

Comment: Hi .. Thank you for your response but my API is not working. How ever for the Google API the requests are limited 25000 per day. :(

Comment: Why is your API not working? As explained in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Limits You can easily get up to 100 000 request per day. If you would like more than this, after you have an implementation of your application you can apply for more request quota here: http://gmaps-ws-console.appspot.com/